# Java Pattern Matcher Incorrectly matches sub string

Tags: java, regex

I have a list of folders at a particular file path
and it gives following file listwhen searched through the cod below

```
File[] fileList = folderListLocation.listFiles(someFileFilter);
//it gives following list
fileList=[NUTS, BOLTS, CAR_COMPONENTS_ADT,CAR_COMPONENTS_ADT1, WINDSHIELD]
```

Now I am trying to get a count for folders of one particular name, that means if I use a pattern matcher to look for CAR_COMPONENTS_ADT, it should give me count as 2, if I look for NUTS using pattern matcher, I should get a count as 1

Now I am using following code to match this file list against some patterns in following code

```
 int count=0;
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternName);

for(File f: fileList){
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(f.getName());
if(matcher.find()){
        count++;
    }
}
```

Now in normal course of things this worked fine, say if patternName = "BIRD", it won't match against the file list and final value of

```
 count will be 0
```

but if patternName = "CAR_COMPONENTS", it results in

```
  count as 2
```

So what I don't understand is that how come pattern matcher match "CAR_COMPONENTS" with "CAR_COMPONENTS_ADT" and "CAR_COMPONENTS_ADT1". Even though its a sub string but I am looking for complete match not partial.

Suggestions and improvements will be very much welcomed. Thanks in advance

Comment: use `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end of the regex: `^CAR_COMPONENTS_ADT$`

Comment: Does that mean that the matches are only expected if the search word is not enclosed with letters or/and `_`? Try `pattern.matcher("(?<![_\\p{L}])" + f.getName() + "(?![_\\p{L}])")`

Comment: will do, I have also tried this that seems to work

Comment: for(File f: fileList){ if(paternName.equals(f){  for(File t:fileList){ Matcher matcher = p.matcher(t)  if(matcher.find(){count++} }  }}

Comment: Oh, sorry, I messed the code a bit, I will post the answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to match a term only when it is not enclosed with letters/underscore.

Use

```
int count=0;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<![_\\p{L}])" + patternName + "(?![_\\p{L}])");
for(File f: fileList) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(f.getName());
    if(matcher.find()){
        count++;
    }
}
```

See the [regex demo with `CAR_COMPONENTS_ADT`](https://regex101.com/r/TEy3II/1) and [a regex demo with `CAR_COMPONENTS`](https://regex101.com/r/TEy3II/2).

The `(?<![_\p{L}])` is a negative lookbehind that matches a location in string that is not immediately preceded with a `_` or any letter (replace `\p{L}` with `[A-Za-z]` or `\p{Alpha}` to only match ASCII letters) and `(?![_\p{L}])` is a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a letter or `_` immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: @Sid Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)) as you are entitled to the upvoting privilege after reaching 15 rep points.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here:

1. The regex of `Pattern.matcher` will not look for the full string unless you add a leading `^` (start of regex) and trailing `$` (end of regex).
2. `file.getName()` will return the name including file extension.

**So, there are two possible solutions:**

1) You could change the regex of the pattern so the matches does only match the full file-name:

```
int count=0;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^" + patternName + "\\.?.+$");
for(File f: fileList){
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(f.getName());
  if(matcher.find()){
    count++;
  }
}
```

Short explanation of the regex:

```python
^NUTS\\.?.+$
^          $    # Start and end of the regex, to match the entire file-name
 NUTS           # The file name you want to check
     \\.?.*     # An (optional) file extension (i.e. `.txt`)
```

2) You could remove the extension, and use an `.equals`:

```java
int count=0;
for(File f: fileList){
  String fileNameWithoutExtension = f.getName().split("\\.")[0];
  if(patternName.equals(fileNameWithoutExtension)){
    count++;
  }
}
```